# Usage and meaning of へと in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I'm not quite sure why in this sentence was inserted と after へ. It would have been wrong to use only へ？moreover, what's the meaning of と in this sentence and why it is used? The sentece is: 彼女は玄関へと歩いていった。